# sort dates inside a graph

Tags: r, sorting, date, bar-chart

I created a barchart with multiple Factors of datapoints i collected over a specific timehoizont. Now I wanted to illustrate these datas in a barchart over time. Therefore I defined the following commands and got the following graph. Here are the datas.

```
Zeitpunkt   20.05.2016  27.05.2016  03.06.2016  10.06.2016  17.06.2016  24.06.2016  01.07.2016  08.07.2016  15.07.2016  22.07.2016  28.07.2016
Innoplattform   1,725806452 2,633333333 3,689655172 2,2 2,846153846 2,571428571 2,884615385 2,131578947 1,954545455 2,956521739 2
WhatsApp    5,548387097 5,533333333 5,775862069 5,96    6,288461538 4,69047619  5,076923077 5,394736842 5,204545455 6,347826087 5,909090909
Skype   0,483870968 1,133333333 1,310344828 1,1 1,346153846 0,261904762 0,480769231 0,526315789 0,545454545 1,369565217 0,659090909
Adobe Connect   0   0,083333333 0   0   0   0   0   0,052631579 0,272727273 0,086956522 0
Facebook    0   0   0,189655172 0,04    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Telefon 1,064516129 0,983333333 0,706896552 0,6 1,519230769 0,166666667 0,115384615 0,368421053 0,409090909 0,347826087 0,227272727
E-Mail  0   1,166666667 1   0,7 1,711538462 0,452380952 0,942307692 0,236842105 1,022727273 2,413043478 2,090909091
```

The data are also over the link available as .csv file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3jgwk76lx3v0i5/Verwendete%20Tools2.csv?dl=0

Based on these datas I defined the datas as dataframe to create a barplot. Therefore are the following commands.

```
Tools <- read.csv(file="Verwendete Tools2.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec=",")

attach(Tools)       # Datensatz Tools laden    

df <- data.frame(X01.07.2016, X03.06.2016, X08.07.2016, X10.06.2016, X15.07.2016, X17.06.2016, X20.05.2016, X22.07.2016, X24.06.2016, X27.05.2016, X28.07.2016)

barplot(as.matrix(df), main="Relative Häufigkeit der für die virtuelle Kommunikation genutzten Tools", ylab = "Relative Häufigkeit", xlab="Zeitpunkte der Umfragen", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, col=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl6Mr.png)

Now what's wrong with this? Normally that's exactly the graph I want to get. But the problem is, the dates on the x-axis are not sorted by dates. R just identifies the dates as normal number not as date.. but when I convert these datapoints to dates, then I also convert the other datapoints to dates, what I doesn't want to.

Can somebody help me, how I can sort these dates inside the graph? Or has somebody another solution how I can create this graph?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Executing your code yields `Error: object 'X01.07.2016' not found`. Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit & improve your post  accordingly. A good post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data & code tries - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session.

Comment: I edited the Question and provided the dataset over dropbox as csv file. I don't understand why you get this error. I tried it in my R commander and it works perfectly to generate the barchart.. but I can't get it in the right order on the x-axis..

Comment: You are using `barplot` on a `matrix`. Your x-axis is determined by the column names. Column names are strings (they must be strings). They are in the exact order that you hard-code them as the columns in your `data.frame()` call. If you want them in a different order, type them in a different order. If you want them displayed differently, use the `names.arg` argument of `barplot` to specify the strings you want as the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3jgwk76lx3v0i5/Verwendete%20Tools2.csv?dl=1", 
              tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"), mode="wb")
Tools <- read.csv(file=tf, header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec=",", check.names = F)
m <- as.matrix(Tools[-1])
barplot(m, beside=TRUE, col=seq_len(nrow(m)))
```

The columns are already sorted in your data frame `Tools`.

Assuming that would not be the case

```
m <- m[,sample(seq_along(colnames(m)))] # shuffle columns
barplot(m, beside=TRUE, col=seq_len(nrow(m)))
```

you could still do

```
m <- m[, order(as.Date(colnames(m), "%d.%m.%Y"))] # order by date
barplot(m, beside=TRUE, col=seq_len(nrow(m)))
```